# Why is CiviRules not firing when the trigger is adding a tag?

Tags: civirules, tags

Using CiviCRM 5.35.1 with Drupal 7. Just installed the new CiviRules extension 2.23. I've been waiting for this because CiviRules has not been working with Tags for a couple of months and it has totally messed up our membership workflow. :-(

Just tested the new version of the CiviRules extension (2.23) and some things are fixed, but not others. When **changing membership status** is the trigger, CiviRules does add the tags it should to the contact and does add the contact to the groups it should. :-)

However, when **adding a tag** is the trigger, it still does not add contacts to groups or remove them from groups as it used to do. :-(

Is anyone else seeing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your problem.

As you can see there are a few outstanding issues with tags: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=tag

As you are probably aware CiviRules is open source like the rest of CiviCRM. That means that issues will be fixed in a number of ways:

- organizations run into bugs and get their own staff to fix them
- organizations run into bugs and pay a CiviCRM partner/developer to fix them

So if you are in a position to either fix the problem or fund someone else fixing it that would be great! Most of the times issues do not get fixed without someone bearing the cost at some point, the power of open source is that the solution is then shared freely.

On top of this CiviCooP sponsors a yearly 2 day sprint to fix as many as the issues as we can in 2 days. But there is no guarantee that the issue that is bugging you is on top of the list (although in this case it probably will be....). This sprint is going to be in the week of 10 May. Any sponsorship for an additional day will be welcome :-)

Comment: I am aware of these options, but this is a case where something used to work correctly, then someone broke it. So why isn't that person responsible for fixing what they broke? Please understand from my "bio" that we are a small non-profit and I have no coding skills. Last year we contributed to a "fix" for another issue, funding most of the work. It didn't actually solve the problem, so we feel that we wasted our money. We are grateful for all the work people do on Civi, but please try to understand this end user's frustration. :-)

Comment: I totally understand the frustration, and regression issues are doubly frustrating. Unfortunately the shop will not give me bread in exchange for gratefulness and I suppose that goes for lots of others too. To be clear: no one "breaks" things on purpose and there is almost never one person clearly responsible for a fix. I did not break it yet I am personally sponsoring fixing it in the first week of May. Wasting your money is not a term I appreciate in this context?

Comment: I understand that no one breaks things on purpose. I wasn't suggesting that. I also wasn't suggesting that you specifically wasted our money. The fix we contributed to was unrelated to this and was paid to someone else. All I am saying is that we supported the work, but it didn't solve the problem. Sorry if I wasn't clear.